# SQL error or missing database (no such function: ready_Date)

Tags: json, kotlin, dao

Пытаюсь создать базу с данными получаемых с API:

```
@Entity(tableName = "get_Ready", indices = [Index(value = ["readyDate"])])
data class GetReady(
    val adult: Int,
    @SerializedName("book_id")
    val bookId: Int,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @SerializedName("id")
    val idGlavs: Int? = null,
    val img: String,
    val lang: String,
    val rating: Double,
    @SerializedName("ready_date")
    val readyDate: String,
    @SerializedName("s_title")
    val sTitle: String,
    @SerializedName("t_title")
    val tTitle: String,
    val title: String
)
```

Записываю:

```
class ImperialListReady(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "adult")
    override val adult_vozrast: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "bookId")
    override val book_Id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "idGlavs")
    override val idGlavs: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "img")
    override val img_Book: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "lang")
    override val lang_book: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "rating")
    override val rating_Books: Double,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "readyDate")
    override val ready_Date: LocalDate,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "sTitle")
    override val orig_Title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tTitle")
    override val ru_Title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    override val title_Glavs: String

): UnitSpecificListReady
```

Вот Dao:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insert(listRadyEnries: List<GetReady>)

@Query("select * from get_Ready where ready_Date(readyDate) >= ready_Date(:startTitle)")
fun getListRadyDao(startTitle: LocalDate): LiveData<List<ImperialListReady>>
```

Ругается на эту строчку:

```
@Query("select * from get_Ready where ready_Date(readyDate) >= ready_Date(:startTitle)")
fun getListRadyDao(startTitle: LocalDate): LiveData<List<ImperialListReady>>
```

При сборке выдает ошибку:

```
ListRadyDao.java:15: error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such function: ready_Date)
public abstract androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<java.util.List<com.example.rulatemvvmtest.data.db.unitilocalized.listready.ImperialListReady>> getListRadyDao(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

Я пытался изменить тип readyDate, но в ошибке говориться, нету функции, я не пойму какая функция нужна ?

Если нужен код конвертора, я могу тоже предоставить.

Comment: Вы с SQL знакомы? А то уже третий ваш вопрос все о том же. Пишете некорректные запросы для Room и удивляетесь что не работает.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Да вы правы, Я решил разобраться полностью с Room, просмотрел всю информацию, сделал отдельно тесты, нашел ошибку. Оказывается я запросы делал, мягко говоря не правильно. Все изменил, теперь работает. Дело было за малым, надо было просто выучить библиотеку Room

Comment: Вот и отлично, что разобрались :)